# in the city you live, in the city where you live, in the city you line in?

Tags: grammar

> How's the weather in the city you live right now?
>
> How's the weather in the city where you live right now?
>
> How's the weather in the city you live in right now?

Are all these three grammatical? I thought the first was grammatical, but I am not sure if it is anymore. It should be where, right? The second is grammatical, and the other two are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. *Are all these three grammatical?*

A. I would suggest, they are not correct use of our language. Firstly "in the city you live right now?" Implies where you live at the current time, not as I suspect you mean *"What is the state of the weather right now"*. Secondly this is not how we would normally phrase this question

---

> **How's the weather where you live?**

*(This is a precise question inquiring about the weather, at your location, at the present time regardless of if the person asking the question has any prior knowledge, or not, of the weather in your area).*

> **What's the weather like now?**

*(It is assumed that you can only comment on the place you are located at that time. The phrase also implies that the person asking the question knew what the weather was like earlier.).*

---

The inclusion of City is not needed in fact it can be very wrong or at least misleading. It is often the case that the weather in one area of a city is different to another area.

> "it is raining on the east side"

What is relevant is the location where you are.

---

**The use of "right now" defines and emphasises this exact precise moment in time.** However I would question the use of this in relation to weather. "It is raining now" is a commonly used phrase but "It is raining right now" is not a phrase I am familiar with. In the sentence *"There is a robber happening down the street, it is happening right now"* We are emphasising that the action is taking place at this moment by using *"right now"*. But do we need to put that emphasis on a common phenomena like rain? I suggest not.